# SQL Replace Multiple Values based on one column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to replace results on up to 9 columns based on one other column value.
If the column "role" is the value "SeniorManagement", I want to replace what would be default hierarchical values with hard values.
Here's how I can accomplish this now:

```
 , CASE
   WHEN d.Role = 'SeniorManagement'  
   THEN (Replace(p.Firstname,'John','Joe')) END as First
 , CASE
   WHEN d.Role = 'SeniorManagement'  
   THEN (Replace(p.Lastname,'TopDog','AssignedPerson')) END as Last
 , CASE...
```

My question is, is there a less verbose way to combine these?

Pseudo ( I know this doens't work :-)

```
 , CASE
    WHEN d.Role = 'SeniorManagement' 
    THEN (Replace(p.Firstname,'John','Joe')) as First 
    THEN (Replace(p.Lastname,'TopDog','AssignedPerson')) as Last
    THEN (Replace(p.Email,'TopDog@wherever','AssignedPerson@wherever')) as Email
```

Thanks

Comment: It might be nice to better understand your need (for example show more of your query), cause with your sample code, I would say : well, just do a `WHERE d.Role='SeniorManagement'`, as you have no else condition in your case when...

Comment: If you want to update records to replace some ppl by other, this way is not really safe it can become a bit messy when people have the same first name. Just use multiple UPDATE statements with different where clauses

Comment: I appreciate the advice. Thanks.  Here's a few extra bits of info.  I am not permitted to overwrite anything.  The reason I am doing this, is the topdog should never be contacted based on any results.  These results will show on a page.  The hierarchy is numeric and each result builds on another. So, if TopDog ends up in these fields - I need to replace with a direct report of his outside the listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using a function?

```
create function dbo.GetColumnValue
(
   @ColumnBasedValue varchar(max),
   @ColumnToReplace varchar(max), --or the type you want
   @ToReplace varchar(max), 
   @Replacement varchar(max)
)
as
BEGIN

return (select case @ColumnBasedValue when 'SeniorManagement'
                      then (Replace(@ColumnToReplace,@ToReplace,@Replacement))
                      else @replaceValue END)

END
```

and use it like

```
select dbo.GetColumnValue(d.Role, p.Firstname,'John','Joe') as First, 
dbo.GetColumnValue(d.Role, p.Lastname,'TopDog','AssignedPerson') as Last..
```

Comment: This looks good. I am going to play with this for a bit.  Thanks

Comment: I am almost there. This has helped greatly! When the topdog ends up in the results, it works flawlessly.  When the topdog is not in the results, it leaves the fields NULL.

Comment: Sweet! I got it.  You led me down the right path Gonzalo. I really appreciate it. I made one change to the end:
   
else @ColumnToReplace END) This allows me to retain the original value if the value is not SeniorManagement.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the context is, you might be able to get away with doing raw selects.

`Select d.Role, 'Joe' as First, 'AssignedPerson' as Last`

and just filter each select with a where clause.

If you want to do multiple ones, use a union.